# Jenkins pipeline not deploying branch to AWS stack even with deployOverride

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline

In a multi branch **Jenkins pipeline**, I have 2 branches, master and 'abc' which is branched from master and is the working branch with commits. After first commit to master, build got generated (due to github jenkins webhook) and it got deployed on AWS stack. After this,

1. Deleted deployed stack from master via Jenkins 'remove' action.(confirmed from AWS cloudformation console)
2. Started 'deploy' action of 'abc' with deployOverride. Logs of build shows the right commit. But AWS stack is still master (verified by running REST urls on the browser.

Any suggestions on the probable reasons. Can give snapshot of build parameter config if required.

Answer (score 0):

Build was actually failing for a checkstyle issue. Hence Jenkins was deploying the last stable build, which was from master branch.
Failed to note the build error since in the 'Stage View' of Jenkins, the box was blue. And was showing success in the pop-up dialog on bringing the mouse over the box.